# How to avoid large data structures in MapReduce?

Tags: python, arrays, hadoop, data-structures, mapreduce

So I am working on a correlation algorithm as practice using hadoop mapreduce and python, and I have a question.

If I have a dataset such as {'A', 'B', 'C'} and I wanted to make pairs ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B, C') etc, do I have to use an array and two for loops to compare all the elements? Is there a way to take advantage of the mapper, reducer, and partitioner functions of MapReduce to avoid the use of a potentially large data structure?

Thank you in advance for any help that you may provide.

Comment: see if the pairs vs stripes approaches are what you are looking for: http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy562/labs16/Lab3-DesignPatterns.pdf (page 8)

Comment: Please read "Combinatoric generators" in https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html.